# API for Distances by Postal Code

Tags: distance, postal-code, service-recommendations

I need to calculate a lot of distances between several cities in Germany which are identified by a postal code, e.g. 10115 for Berlin. I cannot use the Google Maps Distance Matrix API because it would be way too expensive for the amount of requests (even with caching).

Does anybody know a self-hosted/offline API (maybe based on OSM?) where I can request a distance matrix/list of distances between cities identified by postal codes? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything by Googling.

Comment: not an api but http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html has shapefiles with postal codes you cab qgis to calculate the distances locally on your pc.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Mapperz, but I need to calculate distances in a PHP/Java/NodeJS backend, so using qgis is not an option

Answer (score 1):

The TravelTime Search API is a cheaper alternative to Google distance matrix however it is not self hosted / offline. But they do offer a service where you can send a CSV of all origins & destinations and get a matrix of journey times back https://www.traveltimeplatform.com/analytics/

However you can use an API if it doesn't need to be self hosted / offline you can use the free geocoder to translate points in Germany into lat longs http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/reference/geocoding-search/ and then select an origin and query against 1000s of destinations in a single API request. Use time filter for this http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/reference/time-filter/

Disclaimer: I work for the creators of the API.